# How many Axis troops fought on D-Day?

Tags: world-war-two, ww2-european-theater, dday

How many Axis troops fought in Normandy, in the vicinity of the beaches, on D-Day?

I've tried many sources and they have focused primarily on the Allied Forces.

Comment: voted to close: "homework question"; lacks research;

Comment: user2976 - approx. 380,000 Axis troops. See the side bar of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Normandy).

Comment: But you will need add up all the other landings, and other incursions that occurred at or around D-Day for a complete number. I suppose the answer isn't completely simple to find. ;-)

Comment: @LateralFractal: That's for the 6 weeks following the invasion, not for D-Day itself.

Comment: So perhaps we shouldn't close the question. It seems a little more complex than first glance :-)

Comment: 10.000: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-day

Comment: @LennartRegebro :-) that has one of those pernicious 'citation needed' tags.

Comment: I'm with @LateralFractal on this one, and already voted to re-open. However, it would be very helpful if all the information from the comments were moved into the question, especially the various estimates. user2976 please update your question to tell us what you found in your sources and to include what people found for you in the comments.

Comment: There were millions of Axis troops fighting in Italy and the Russian front on that day.

Comment: Question has not been updated; still looks trivial. Please update the question with the relevant information from the comments and explain why this question isn't answered on wikipedia.  I accept that it isn't answered there, but the question as it stands is a "bring me a rock" question.

Comment: @Oldcat: I limited the question to Normandy and France. Actually, the Axis numbers are a bit shadowy, so this question is worth exploring.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing these numbers in context with how Germany divided its forces to other possible landing sites, and whether efforts by the Allies to confuse Germany as to its intentions were successful.

Comment: I think in the questions current state it should be left closed. There may be an interesting angle on how the forces were deployed, or on the tooth to tail ratio of axis forces in Normandy. However, the question has not be edited in a way that suggests it after any other answer than the simple one (50,000 for d-day, 380,000  for the battle for Normandy: check wikipedia). This should remain closed.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [US Military Academy map of Normandy Operations June 6-12, 1944](http://www.usma.edu/history/SiteAssets/SitePages/World%20War%20II%20Europe/WWIIEurope55.gif) the German divisions actually on or just behind the Normandy beach area on June 6 are as follows (West to East):

1. 709 Infantry
2. 243 Infantry
3. 91 Infantry
4. 352 Infantry
5. 716 Infantry
6. 21 Panzer

According to [this source](http://www.bayonetstrength.150m.com/German/german_army.htm) the nominal infantry strength of a German Infantry Division in the 1943-45 time period comprised:

> 3 regiments * 2 [grenadier battalions](http://www.bayonetstrength.150m.com/German/Infanterie/german_grenadier_battalion%201943%20to%201945.htm) * 708 all ranks = ~ 4,250 all ranks
>   1 fusilier battalion (similar to grenadier battalion) = ~ 700 all ranks
>   1 Engineer battalion * 3 Pioneer companies (unknown) = ~ 700 all ranks (?)
>   1 Artillery regiment (manning unknown; 10 per gun average yields ~820 all ranks):
>    36 @ 10.5 cm howitzer
>    12 @ 15 cm howitzer
>    12 @ 7.5 cm anti-tank gun
>    10 @ Assault gun
>    12 @ 2cm AA

This was supplemented by additional staff and support troops for each division. Grenadier battalions possessed 3@7.5 cm anti-tank guns, 36@panzerschrecks, and numerous mortars of various sizes included in the manning above. Ball park something in the neighbourhood of 8,000 to 10,000 men per division.

The Panzer Division at that time was similar in structure, with two Grenadier regiments replaced by Panzer Grenadier (motorized) regiments, and the third regiment replaced by a Panzer (armoured) regiment. This would supply roughly 2/3 the infantry strength of an infantry  regiment, supported by two Panzer battalions (nominally ~50 tanks each) and a reconnaissance battalion in addition to the integrated engineer, artillery, anti-tank and other support troops.

In total this puts the total (nominal) field strength of the Axis units engaged on June 6, 1944 at roughly 35,000 riflemen/pioneers (5@6,000 + 1@4,500), 100 tanks plus supporting artillery, anti-tank and staff units.

As also noted by the map, this force is increased over the following 6 days by the arrival of these additional units:

1. 77 Infantry (June 10-12)
2. 17 SS Panzer Grenadier (June 11-12)
3. 275 Infantry (June 12-19)
4. 3 Paratroop (June 10-12)
5. 2 Panzer (June 10-11)
6. Panzer Lehr (June 10)
7. 12 SS Panzer (June 7-8)
8. 711 Infantry (unlabelled, possibly available from June 6)
9. 263 Infantry (June 11, arrives west of St. Lo as reserve)

**Updated for major artillery components and estimates for Fusilier and Pioneer battalions.**